# Make "backups" icon go away

Tags: unity, 14.04, backup

Shortly after installing Ubuntu 14.04, I started getting this annoying black-box icon on my application launcher.  I have to click on it and say "skip backups" every time I restart my computer to make it go away.  I never used backup software before; I have my own methods.  How can I make this go away?  Is it a standalone program or part of the new OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Deja-dup backup software it pre-installed with Ubuntu. To can uninstall it from **Terminal**(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove deja-dup
```

**source**: http://vikrambuzz.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-remove-ubuntu-deja-dup-backup.html

Or

If you want to just change the settings so that i never asks for backup. Goto ->system settings(top right)-> select backups and change settings.
[image]